# Can I make Ext JS window resizable only in width

Tags: extjs

Can I make Ext JS window resizable only in width. As I know resizable property can receive some other values than `true` and `false`. May be I'm wrong I don't know, but if you look at sencha architect and look for `resizable` property it's not a checkbox, so as I guess it can receive something other than bool values. Any way my point here Is, Can I make window just resizable only in width and if yes, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `resizeHandles` config:

```
new Ext.window.Window({
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    title: 'Foo',
    autoShow: true,
    resizeHandles: 'w e'
});
```